# Does any one know what TE DX Plug-In it is?

Tags: appexchange, partner-communities

I'm reading trailblazer score document and I found follow description that "Run the TE DX Plug-In to verify use of technologies" in this link:

https://appexchangeguides.relayto.com/e/appexchange-trailblazer-score-coaching-guide-l71mmyuf2piou/LEQvw2vn

I can't found any document tell about this "TE DX Plug-In" it is, does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slide is overly abbreviated, it appears the full name is the [isvte-sfdx-plugin](https://github.com/forcedotcom/isvte-sfdx-plugin), which you can find over on GitHub, including installation directions. To get started, just use:

```
sfdx plugins:install isvte-sfdx-plugin
```

For the record, I knew that DX was often a short abbreivation of sfdx, so I tried "te sfdx plugin" on Google, and this is what I came up with. I'm pretty sure this is the intended plugin, as it closely matches the definition I expected from the sentence you copied (namely, it speaks to "technical enablement").